# How to get multiple places names in Google Places API?

Tags: python, django, google-maps, google-places-api

In my `Django` project, I let users to mark in which city they were recently. I use for this Google Places API - autocomplete with map.

I have multiple use cases which I can't figure out to work with **Google Places API T&C** and this is one of them:

There is a filter of users. Each user have chosen their **last visited place** (so I can store `place_id`).

When user filtered 100 users, they are showed one by one by their cards in results. The card should contain the user's last visited place.

So I have to show 100 cards with 100 places (cities).

How to do that if I have only `place_id`'s? Should I send 100 detail requests to `Google Places API` to get name of each city?

```
def user_filter(request):
    filtered_users = ....
    for user in filtered_users:
        api_result = request.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=MY_API_KEY')
        recent_city_name = parse_from_result(api_result)
    ....
    return render(request,....)
```

Although this should teoretically work, it is a big overkill  - time consuming and API requests consuming. Is there a better way to do that?

I didn't find any bulk request option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that Google Maps API doesn't support bulk operations and sending hundreds of requests is certainly time consuming.

I believe you can use paragraph 10.5 (d) of the Terms of Service that reads

> *No caching or storage.* You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that **you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency** (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage:
>
> - is temporary (and in no event more than 30 calendar days);
> - is secure;
> - does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
> - does not modify attribution in any way.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#section_10_5

I believe, you are compliant with the text that I marked in bold. Your purpose is to improve a performance of the application, so you can temporarily store a hash map that relates place ID and city name and refresh your temporary storage every 30 days to be compliant with Terms of Service.

I hope this helps!

Comment: `place_id` can be stored in your database:


> Place IDs are exempt from the caching restrictions stated in Section 3.2.3(b) of the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service. Once you've identified the place ID for a place, you may reuse that value the next time you look up that place. For more information, see Save place IDs for later use below.

Link - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id#place-details